# Как ограничить движение камеры? Чтобы она двигалась в одну сторону, а в другую нет

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как ограничить движение камеры, как в игре Hill Climb Racing? То есть, чтобы камера следовала за персонажем в одну сторону, но не следовала за ним в другую сторону. Как сделать такую камерую? Перед ответом, пожалуйста, прочитайте то, что написано ниже.

Вот у меня есть два персонажа на выбор, первый может лететь вверх если кнопка зажата, и он может падать вниз если кнопка не нажата. Он двигается с помощью transform.Translate. Второй может летать вверх и падать вниз также как и первый персонаж, но второй персонаж двигается вверх с помощью AddForce, а падает благодаря гравитации в компоненте rigidbody2D.

Я примерно понимаю как для первого персонажа можно сделать камеру, которая летит за ним вверх, но не падает вниз. Меня больше интересует второй персонаж, так как у него скорость всегда разная (из-за AddForce и rigidbody2D), и я не могу понять, каким образом сделать камеру летящую за вторым персонажем вверх, но не падающую вниз?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

один скрипт на обоих персонажей:

```
var cameraPos = camera.transform.position;
var playerPos = player.transform.position;

if (cameraPos.y < playerPos.y) {
    camera.transform.position = new Vector3(cameraPos.x, playerPos.y,cameraPos.z);
}
```

засунуть в апдейт.

Если нужно статическое смещение, а не персонаж по центру экрана - делай статическое смещение в необходимую сторону

И оба персонажа должны двигаться при помощи AddForce или ручного задавания velocity. Если ты не можешь обьяснить наверняка причину почему должен двигаться через транслейт - то ты делаешь что-то не так. Если есть возможность использовать физику - всегда используй физику.

В даном случае ты хочешь двигать персонажа с одинаковой скоростью - так задавай физическую скорость равной необходимому уровню на каждом кадре.